# How to setState Array in ArrayObject React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've been sitting around for a while trying to figure out how to do this I've scoured a lot of documentation on StackOverFlow (maybe I missed it)

```
this.state = {
        data: {
                labels: [],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        data: []
                    }
                ]
            }
        };
```

i tried with below code how can i setState CONCAT for 2 arrays Labels:[] and data:[]

my code:

```
  this.setState(a => ({
       data: {
          labels: this.state.data.labels.concat(x.month), <- is this correct?
          datasets: [
                      {
                        data: this.state.data.datasets.map(x=> x.data.concat(x.money/1000))
                     or //data: this.state.data.datasets[0].data.concat(x.money/1000))
                       }
                    ]
              }
           }
        )
     )
```

JS

```
data: {

                labels: [],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        data: []
                    }
                ]
       }
```

how to point to data array?

Comment: What is `x`? What is the error message that you're seeing?

Comment: x is one element add into array

Answer (score 0):

As you might be aware, the state update in react/react-native are asynchronous. Therefore the code you have written might cause some weird behavior sometimes. For example, simultaneously multiple function call for that state update might lead to the unexpected end state.

Instead, you can update your state as following

```js
this.setState((state, props) => ({
   data: {
      labels: state.data.labels.concat(x.month),
      datasets: state.data.datasets.map(({data}) => ({data: data.concat(x.money/1000)}))
    }
  })
)
```

Comment: TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() 
method  it gave an error
i think it error here "data[]"

Comment: Can you please try again with this code now? @ThắngTrươngKhắc
The modification it have with your code is, it is ensuring the use of updated state every time you call the function.

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.data.datasets.data.concat'), i think you can't call data in dataset because it's properties of array datasets, can't use character ' . '

Comment: @ThắngTrươngKhắc 
Correct, updated the final one

Comment: Error: Exception in HostFunction: Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different.

[[128,128,128,128,5],[5,3,5,5,5],[[1377,"RNSVGText",61,{"dy":[],"rotate":[],"fill":3439329279,"x":[64],"y":[205],"matrix":[1,0,-0,1,0,0],"dx":[],"propList":["fill"],"font":{"textAnchor":"middle","fontSize":12}}],[1377,[1375]],[1]],3074]

Comment: @ThắngTrươngKhắc This seems like a different issue. You can elaborate the same for the solution